# How to improve Tesseract accuracy

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, tesseract, opencv

I am trying to run OCR on set of images that are similar but can vary in size. For some reason I cannot get a predictable result. Is there anything I can do do get better results.

Tesseract with or without cv2 preprocessing works beautifully on some images and fails on some and there is no pattern. Images are more or less similar.
[Upper image represents processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vATKQ.png)

```
def filter_img(img):
  # Read pil image as cv2
  img = np.array(img)
  img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

  # Converting image to grayscale (important for applying threshold)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  #Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
  kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
  # img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
  img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
  # Apply blur to smooth out the edges
  img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
  # img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
  # Apply threshold to get image with only b&w (binarization)
  img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
  img = Image.fromarray(img)
  img = ImageOps.expand(img,border=2,fill='black')
  visualize.show_labeled_image(img,boxes)
  return img

# Applying Tesseract OCR
def run_tesseract(img):    
    # Tesseract cmd setup
    # pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "tesseract"
    whitelist = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + ".-"
    parameters = '-c load_freq_dawg=0 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="{}"'.format(whitelist)
    psm = 8
    custom_oem_psm_config = "--dpi 300 --oem 3 --psm {psm} {parameters}".format(parameters=parameters, psm=psm)
    try:
      text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_oem_psm_config, timeout=2)
      return text.strip()
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("TIMEOUT")
    return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image format is highly consistent, you might consider using split images. And after ocr the image, use conditional judgments on the first letter or number for error-prone areas, such as 0 and O are confusing. Of course, all of the above is only valid if the image is highly consistent.

```
enter code here
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import pytesseract
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'D://Program Files/Tesseract- 
    OCR/tesseract.exe'

    img = cv2.imread('vATKQ.png')

    img2 = img[100:250, 180:650]  #split to region you want
    plt.imshow(img2)
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img2)
    print(text)
```

Comment: image is somewhat consistent, isn't split image for super large images? Can you elaborate your answer. Thanks :)